# Angular router: Retain entire url even if partial prefix url is matched

Tags: angular

By default pathToMatch property is prefix.
I have configured a url with

```
{path: 'courses', component: CoursesComponent},
{path: '**', redirectTo: 'courses'}
```

I opened the browser and redirected my page to say https://localhost:4200/#/courses/12/someInfo

The url can be **/courses/../../../..** till any level of depth.

Angular router internally redirects to https://localhost:4200/#/courses url.

I want to persist the other info also in above scenario which is **.../12/someInfo**

I need that info because inside my CoursesComponent i am loading a non angular microservice which needs that url info. That microservice internally manages to initialize different courses urls based on hashable url.

How can an maintain the url on pageload without allowing angular to trim url to defined routes?

Comment: Is `/courses` a valid url, or is it always followed by `/{number}/{someInfo}`? I'm assuming both `{number}` and `{someInfo}` are changeable parameters here?

Comment: /courses is a valid url.

Comment: actually i was also looking if i can remove intial / after hash. something like /#courses/id/something instead of /#/courses/..

Answer (score 0):

I tried a hack and it worked...

```
{path: 'courses', component: CoursesComponent, children: [
  {path: '**', component: RenderYourMicroserviceComponent}
]},
{path: '**', redirectTo: 'courses'}
```

Comment: Why is this better than @Oussail's answer? Their answer isn't a hack - it is a standard method for handling this situation.

Comment: I am not saying better solution or bad solution. I want to address all types of url.
for instance. i have path courses/id/someInfo/all/id/data/tasks/t1. Such a url also exists. So to cover all use cases i just think with children accept all urls.

Comment: I'm curious now, how do the urls get formed if you're not aware of what could be in them? And why not use query params?

Comment: consider you have an old app with routes defined. we use to update hash urls to render certain peice of code inside a container. Now i want my old app to work seemlessly inside my new angular container, which has new code as well as old code. Hence i need it. The point is i can go inside old app and get all types of defined urls (7-8) urls. but i wanted simple generic solution. if tommorow i am creating new extension to courses, it should work seamlessely. The power i get is i can slowly update my old app coed to new app. Note: Its a single page app.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not the best, also your code redirects to courses because is the the default route when the route write doesn't exist.

If you want to pass a finite number of params through the url, for example, id and title, you can do the following:

```
{path: 'courses/:id/:title', component: CoursesComponent},
```

This example will work for your url: https://localhost:4200/#/courses/12/someInfo. But the url will always have to be "/courses/id/title"

If you want to pass more information I recommend you use a service like this one:

**courseService**

```
@Injectable()
export class CourseService {
   currentCourse: Course;

   getCurrentCourseInfo(): Course {
     return this.currentCourse;
 }
  setCurrentCourseInfo(course: Course): void {
    this.currentCourse = course;
 }
}
```

Then in your origin component:

```
goToCourseDetail(course: Course): void {
  this.courseService.setCurrentCourseInfo(course);
  this.router.navigate(['courses/' + id]);
}
```

to retrieve the information on the **microservice component**:

```
this.course =  this.currentService.getCurrentCourseInfo();
```

now in *this.course* you will have the whole course info available